# How to list Raspbian environment variables

Tags: raspbian

I'm trying to change the LANG variable in Raspbian but would like to list those that already exist.  My attempt to run MRTG yields an error message indicating the ENV variable should not be set to UTF-8.

Answer (score 4):

`env` is the shell command for Unix and Unix-like operating systems like Raspbian to list the currently set environment variables. Raspbian is in that respect nothing special but just the friendly neighbourhood Linux.